# How do I show that the line $lx+my+1=0$ touches a fixed circle, provided $l^2-5m^2+6l+1=0$?

Tags: analytic-geometry

A high school geometry problem.

> How do I show that if the line $lx+my+1=0$ touches a fixed circle, provided $4l^2-5m^2+6l+1=0$?

Comment: Every line touches a circle.

Comment: The equation that you said "provided" does not define a circle. It defines a hyperbola. Check the signs in your equations once more...

Comment: We can roll a coin on any line in space, Can't we?

Comment: Oh so sorry ...i just checked it was 4l^2.

Comment: My teacher has also asked me to find the radius and centre of that circle ...it would be appreciated if you can give me a hint bout how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

You have to find such point $S(a,b)$ and $r>0$ that $${|la+mb+1|\over \sqrt{m^2+l^2}} =r$$

To do that think of three diffrent pair of $l,m$ in orther to get 3 lines and calculate their intesection points. Then calculate the radius of it incircle and coordinates of incenter.

> But, as far as I can see three is no such circle. If we say $m=0$ we get two lines parallel to $y$ axsis and if we take $l=0$ we get two lines parallel to $x$ axsis. These lines form rectangle which is not a square so there is no such circle.